# Tab-modality in windows application

Tags: delphi, windows-xp

Using Delphi 2009 on Windows XP to develop desktop application.

Is there any way to make a windows dialog modal to a tab, instead of application.  How can I achieve this?  Threads? any frameworks supporting this?

Something similar to

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,
Pavan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to simulate this is:

1. Temporarily disable all child controls of the tab sheet
2. Create a Form
3. Set its `Parent` to the tab sheet
4. Set `FormStyle := fsStayOnTop`
5. Set `BorderStyle := bsNone`

This way you have a dialog on top of a tab sheet and it's the only thing that users can interact with on this tab sheet, but it doesn't block the main form ui or other tab sheets.

Comment: It simulates only the look, but not model functionality i.e., the code that brings up this dialog needs to wait for modal result of this dialog and at the same time it should be able to bring up another dialog in another tabsheet and wait for the modal result. Tried to simulate this behaviour using below logic.

Comment: SendMessage(Handle, CM_ACTIVATE, 0, 0);
    SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCACTIVATE, Ord(True), 0);
    ModalResult := 0;
    repeat
      Application.HandleMessage;
      if Application.Terminated then
        ModalResult := mrCancel;
    until ModalResult <> 0;
    Result := ModalResult;
    SendMessage(Handle, CM_DEACTIVATE, 0, 0);                            but this does not work, as it expects the second dialog in second tab to close before closing first dialog in first tab.

Comment: Why wait? What is wrong with reacting on the OnClick event from a button?

Comment: The dialog doesnot handle anything by itself, but it is the responsibility of calling thread.  In one sentence, I am looking for a function like "ShowModal", but modal to a tab or any control instead of entire application.

Comment: @Pavan: Mixing thread code and VCL is not a good idea, you could signal the processing thread of a button press event. One possibility is to set a flag to `True` when the dialog was closed by the user and check in the thread if that flag has been set, otherwise wait using 'Sleep' or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use something like this to make a window modal

WindowList : Pointer;
WindowList := DisableTaskWindows(MyForm.Handle);

and

EnableTaskWindows(WindowList);

to un-modal it.  This should allow you to simulate a modal form.